# Changing the angles of the arrows in tikzcd

Tags: tikz-cd

I have the following code for the commutative diagram.

[image: Commutative Diagram]

```
\begin{tikzcd}[column sep=huge, row sep=huge]
    & G/A \arrow[dl, "\pi"] \arrow[dr, "\sigma"] \arrow[dd, "\omega"]& \\
    G \arrow[dr, "\rho"] & & (G/A)/(B/A) \arrow[dl, "\theta"] \\
    & G/B &
\end{tikzcd}
```

As you can see, it is not very symmetric. How would you be able to kind of change the angle of the arrows so the two sides are similar with the same angle?

Comment: Maybe `minimum width=5em`, will help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `between origins`, but the column separation should be bigger.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzcd}[column sep={6em,between origins}, row sep=huge]
& G/A \arrow[dl, "\pi"] \arrow[dr, "\sigma"] \arrow[dd, "\omega"] & \\
G \arrow[dr, "\rho"] & & (G/A)/(B/A) \arrow[dl, "\theta"] \\
& G/B &
\end{tikzcd}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use `minimum width` to set a minimal distance. For label position you can use `anchor=center` and some constant `xshift,yshift` of `1em`.

Here my suggestion. I think its not 100% symmetric, but nearly.

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzcd}[minimum width=5em,column sep=scriptsize, row sep=scriptsize]
& G/A \arrow{dd}[anchor=center,xshift=1ex,yshift=0ex]{\omega} 
\arrow{dr}[anchor=center,xshift=1ex,yshift=1ex]{\sigma} 
\arrow{dl}[anchor=center,xshift=-1ex,yshift=1ex]{\pi}
&  \\
G  \arrow{dr}[anchor=center,xshift=-1ex,yshift=-1ex]{\psi} &
& (G/A)/(B/A)  \arrow{dl}[anchor=center,xshift=1ex,yshift=-1ex]{\omega}\\
 & G/B 
& 
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative solution:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}
 \begin{tikzcd}[column sep=huge, row sep=huge]
    & G/A \arrow[dl, "\pi", swap] \arrow[dr, to path={ -- node[midway,above right=-1pt] {\scriptsize $\sigma$}  (\tikztotarget.north west)}] \arrow[dd, "\omega", below]& \\
    G \arrow[dr, to path={-- node[midway,below left] {\scriptsize $\rho$} (\tikztotarget)}] & & (G/A)/(B/A) \arrow[dl, to path={(\tikztostart.south west) -- node[midway,below right] {\scriptsize $\theta$} (\tikztotarget)}] \\
    & G/B &
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

[image]